# Shell script works in win10, not on Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I am using akamai purge script from the [Link](https://community.akamai.com/thread/6186-bash-fast-purge-via-ccu-v3-api) and modified a little bit, so variables are in the file itself. This code successfully runs and purges object on win10, but when I run it on linux it does not purge, also it displays in console same text. I am not that fimiliar with shell scripts, any ideas what is wrong?

```
## Functions ------------------------------------------------------------------

function _get_property {
  [ "$#" -lt 2 ] && return 1
  local RC=$1
  local PROP=$2
  local value=$(cat ${RC} | sed "/^\s*#/d;s/\s*#[^\"']*$//" | grep ${PROP} | tail -n 1 | cut -d '=' -f2- )
  if [ -z "${value}" ]; then
    return 1
  else
    echo ${value}
    return 0
  fi
}

function get_properties {
  local file="${1}"

  declare -A aka_props

  aka_props[client_secret]=$( _get_property "${file}" client_secret )
  [ -z "${aka_props[client_secret]}" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Please, set variable client_secret in file ${file}!!!"; exit 1; }
  aka_props[client_token]=$( _get_property "${file}" client_token )
  [ -z "${aka_props[client_token]}" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Please, set variable client_token in file ${file}!!!"; exit 1; }
  aka_props[access_token]=$( _get_property "${file}" access_token )
  [ -z "${aka_props[access_token]}" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Please, set variable access_token in file ${file}!!!"; exit 1; }
  aka_props[host]=$( _get_property "${file}" host )
  [ -z "${aka_props[host]}" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Please, set variable host in file ${file}!!!"; exit 1; }

  aka_props[network]=$( _get_property "${file}" network )
  [ -z "${aka_props[network]}" ] && aka_props[network]="staging"
  aka_props[action]=$( _get_property "${file}" action )
  [ -z "${aka_props[action]}" ] && aka_props[network]="invalidate"
  aka_props[type]=$( _get_property "${file}" type )
  [ -z "${aka_props[type]}" ] && aka_props[network]="type"

  declare -p aka_props | cut -d '=' -f2-

  return 0
}

declare -A AKA_PROPS
AKA_PROPS[client_secret]=<client_secret>
AKA_PROPS[client_token]=<client_token>
AKA_PROPS[access_token]=<access_token>
AKA_PROPS[host]=<host>
AKA_PROPS[network]="production"
AKA_PROPS[action]="delete"
AKA_PROPS[type]="url"

function mk_nonce {
  local s=$1
  if [ -z ${s} ]; then s=$( date -u +'%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S%z' ); fi
  echo -n "${s}" | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f1 | sed 's/.\{4\}/&-/g' | sed 's/.$//'
}

function base64_hmac_sha256 {
  [ "$#" -lt 2 ] && return 1
  local key=$1
  local value=$2

  echo -ne "${value}"| openssl sha256 -binary -hmac "${key}" | openssl base64
}

function base64_sha256 {
   [ "$#" -lt 1 ] && return 1
   local value=$1

   echo -ne "${value}" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 | openssl base64
}

function mk_auth_header {
  [ "$#" -lt 3 ] && return 1
  local -n aka_props=$1
  local timestamp=$2
  local nonce=$3

  echo -n "EG1-HMAC-SHA256 client_token=${AKA_PROPS[client_token]};access_token=${AKA_PROPS[access_token]};timestamp=${timestamp};nonce=${nonce};"  
  #echo -n "EG1-HMAC-SHA256 client_token=${aka_props[client_token]};access_token=${aka_props[access_token]};timestamp=${timestamp};nonce=${nonce};"
}

function sign_data {
  [ "$#" -lt 2 ] && return 1
  local key=$1
  local -n data_to_sign=$2

  #local data="${data_to_sign[method]}\t${data_to_sign[scheme]}\t${data_to_sign[host]}\t${data_to_sign[request_uri]}\t${data_to_sign[canonical_headers]}\t${data_to_sign[hash_content]}\t${data_to_sign[auth_header]}"
  local data="${data_to_sign[method]}\t${data_to_sign[scheme]}\t${data_to_sign[host]}\t${data_to_sign[request_uri]}\t\t${data_to_sign[hash_content]}\t${data_to_sign[auth_header]}"
  base64_hmac_sha256 "${key}" "${data}"
}

function mk_body {
  local type="${1}"
  local objects="${2}"
  local domain="${3}"

  local arr_objects
  local objs

  IFS=',' read -r -a arr_objects <<< "${objects}"
  for i in ${!arr_objects[@]}
  do
    local tmp=$( echo ${arr_objects[i]} | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' -e 's,/,\\/,g' )
    if [ "${type}" == "cpcode" ]; then
      objs="${objs},${tmp}"
    else
      objs="${objs},\"${tmp}\""
    fi
  done

  objs=$( echo "${objs}" | sed 's/^,//' )

  if [ "${type}" == "url" ]; then
    echo "{\"hostname\":\"${domain}\",\"objects\":[${objs}]}"
  else
    echo "{\"objects\":[${objs}]}"
  fi
}


## Options --------------------------------------------------------------------

P_NAME=${0##*\/}

#CONF=./.akarc
#[ ! -f ${CONF} ] && CONF=./.akarc
#[ ! -f ${CONF} ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: configuration file not found (~/.akarc or /etc/.akarc)"; exit 1; }

#declare -A AKA_PROPS=$( get_properties "${CONF}" );

usage() {
cat << EOF
usage: ${P_NAME} [OPTIONS] -o <obj1[,obj2,obj3,...]>

Purge the Akamai cache via CCU REST API v3.

REMARKS
  Please create a config file in ~/.akarc or /etc/.akarc

PARAMETERS:
    -o | --objects        List of objects to purge (with comma separated values)


OPTIONS:
    -t | --type           Type of objects
                        Possible values: url, cpcode or tag
                        Default: ${AKA_PROPS[type]}

    -d | --domain         Domain site (es. your.domain.com).
                      To use with type=url

    -a | --action         The desired action to manage the cache
                        Possible values: invalidate or delete
                        Default: ${AKA_PROPS[action]}

    -n | --network        The network on which you want to invalidate or delete content
                        Possible values: staging or production
                        Default: ${AKA_PROPS[network]}

-h | --help           Show this message
-v | --version        Show version


CONFIG FILE:

  In the config file the following values have to been declared:
    client_secret = <your client secret>
    client_token = <your client token>
    access_token = <your access token>
    host = <your akamai host>

  There is the possibility to set the default values:
    network = <staging | production>
    action  = <invalidate | delete>
    type    = <url | cpcode | tag>

  If no values are declared the default ones are:
    network = staging
    action  = invalidate
    type    = url
EOF
}

ARGS=$( getopt -o "d:t:o:a:n:hv" -l "domain:,type:,objects:,action:,network:,help,version" -n "$0" -- "$@" )
eval set -- "$ARGS"

VERSION=0.2

NETWORK=${AKA_PROPS[network]}
ACTION=${AKA_PROPS[action]}
TYPE=${AKA_PROPS[type]}

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -d | --domain )
      DOMAIN=${2}
      shift 2
    ;;
    -t | --type )
      TYPE=${2}
      shift 2
    ;;
    -o | --objects )
      OBJECTS=${2}
      shift 2
    ;;
    -a | --action )
      ACTION=${2}
      shift 2
    ;;
    -n | --network )
      NETWORK=${2}
      shift 2
    ;;
    -h | --help )
      usage
      exit 0
    ;;
    -v | --version )
      echo $0 version: $VERSION
      exit 0
    ;;
    -- )
      shift
      break
    ;;
    * )
      >&2 echo "Internal error!"
      exit 1
    ;;
  esac
done

## Main -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[ -z "${TYPE}" ] || [ -z "${OBJECTS}" ] && { usage; exit 1; }
[ "${TYPE}" == "url" ] && [ -z "${DOMAIN}" ] && { usage; exit 1; }

[ "${TYPE}" != "url" ] && [ ! -z "${DOMAIN}" ] && { echo "WARNING: type is different of url then -d,--domain will be ignored ..."; }

[ "${TYPE}" != "url" ] && [ "${TYPE}" != "cpcode" ] && [ "${TYPE}" != "tag" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Possible value of OBJECT TYPE is url, cpcode or tag"; exit 1; }
[ "${NETWORK}" != "staging" ] && [ "${NETWORK}" != "production" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Possible value of NETWORK is staging or production"; exit 1; }
[ "${ACTION}" != "invalidate" ] && [ "${ACTION}" != "delete" ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: Possible value of ACTION is invalidate or delete"; exit 1; }

BODY=$( mk_body "${TYPE}" "${OBJECTS}" "${DOMAIN}" )
[ $(echo -ne "${BODY}" | wc -c ) -gt 131072 ] && { >&2 echo "ERROR: The body size is greater than 131072!!!" exit 1; }

TIMESTAMP=$( date -u +'%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S%z' )
NONCE=$( mk_nonce ${TIMESTAMP} )
SIGN_KEY=$( base64_hmac_sha256 ${AKA_PROPS[client_secret]} ${TIMESTAMP} )
AUTH_HEADER=$( mk_auth_header AKA_PROPS ${TIMESTAMP} ${NONCE} )

declare -A DATA_TO_SIGN=( [method]="POST"
                      [scheme]="https"
                      [host]="${AKA_PROPS[host]}"
                      [request_uri]="/ccu/v3/${ACTION}/${TYPE}/${NETWORK}"
                      [hash_content]=$( base64_sha256 "${BODY}" )
                      [auth_header]=$( mk_auth_header AKA_PROPS ${TIMESTAMP} ${NONCE}) )


SIGNED_DATA=$( sign_data "${SIGN_KEY}" DATA_TO_SIGN )
SIGNED_AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: ${AUTH_HEADER}signature=${SIGNED_DATA}"

H_JSON="Content-Type: application/json"

echo curl -s -H \"Expect:\" \
         -H \"User-Agent:${P_NAME}\" \
         -H \"Accept:${H_JSON}\" \
         -H \"${H_JSON}\" \
         -H \"${SIGNED_AUTH_HEADER}\" \
         -X POST -d \'${BODY}\' \"${DATA_TO_SIGN[scheme]}://${DATA_TO_SIGN[host]}${DATA_TO_SIGN[request_uri]}\" | bash -x | jq .

   exit 0
```

Comment: 1. Try to add `#!/bin/bash` at the first line of the code; 2. How do you run the script on Linux? Be sure your file executable (`chmod +x script.sh`) and run as `bash script.sh` or `./script.sh`

Comment: Added `#!/bin/bash` and file has 0777 permission and running like you wrote. still nothing.

Comment: Again, how are you running it? If you run it with `sh script.sh`, then the shebang does no good whatsoever.

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of "code smells" here -- things that aren't quite bugs, but are definitely practices that can cause or lead to bugs. Missing quotes, all-caps variable names (which are used for variables with meaning to the OS and shell, whereas [names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)), etc.

Comment: Having a [mcve] that reproduced the specific bug you're hitting, rather than just providing the whole script with nothing to narrow down a specific issue, would do this question a great deal of good.

Comment: With respect to finding the aforementioned bug-prone practices -- run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it flags.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
AKA_PROPS[client_secret]=<client_secret>
```

Hope you're replacing `<client_secret>` with its actual value as in Linux, the `</>` is meant for redirection. Apart from that, I would suggest below things.

- Add a shebang(`#!/bin/bash`) to the top of the file
- Then run `dos2unix script_name`
- Finally run the script.

Comment: I used `<client_secret>` to cover the secter. I use `AKA_PROPS[client_secret]="secretsecret"` like this

Comment: `dos2unix: converting file ./aka_purge2.sh to Unix format ...`, but still nothing :( anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Associative arrays like ${AKA_PROPS[network]} are available for bash 4.0 or newer so first hing to do is to check bash version on your Linux against the version on Window$.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

Another good thing to do is to add your changes after line 119 on the original script. Make sure values are properly quoted and that all values in .akarc file are present in your script.

```
#declare -A AKA_PROPS=$( get_properties "${CONF}" );
declare -A AKA_PROPS
AKA_PROPS[client_secret]=<client_secret>
AKA_PROPS[client_token]=<client_token>
AKA_PROPS[access_token]=<access_token>
AKA_PROPS[host]=<host>
AKA_PROPS[network]="production"
AKA_PROPS[action]="delete"
AKA_PROPS[type]="url"
```

You can test with -h option since AKA_PROPS values will be shown in the help text (e.g. Default: ${AKA_PROPS[type]}).

Comment: Associative arrays are present in bash 4.0 -- they do not require 4.2.